# Text is italic in Chrome, Firefox and VS Code

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts, 18.10, visual-studio-code

All (most of the text) from some sites is appearing to be italic with some specific font as shown in the pictures.

[image: GitHub]

[image: Microsoft VS Code]

[image: VS Code]

Why is this happening? How do I correct it? The font settings on Chrome (Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)), Firefox (Firefox Quantum, 64.0 (64-bit)) and VS Code (Version 1.30.2) are the default.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11398943/5987698

Comment: Check the font settings in the system settings. I can't remember where they are exactly on 18.10. You might need to use Gnome Tweak Tool to access them.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually an app for changing font settings in distros that can have fonts other than sans-serif or something else that looks familiar. Just search "fonts" in the app search bar and play with some settings until you find a font that looks better. (I don't have screenshots or anything because I use Ubuntu Mate so I have no idea what exactly the steps are, but they are usually almost identical on all distros, including non Ubuntu-based ones).